# How to deploy to Vercel staging environment using bitbucket pipelines and Vercel CLI

Tags: next.js, bitbucket, vercel

I have 3 environments (preview, staging and production)
Also I followed [these](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/ci-cd/bitbucket-pipelines) steps to set everything up but I noticed that staging is picking up preview environment variables because of this line:

```
- vercel pull --yes --environment=preview --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN
```

I tried to find the correct value for `--environment` argument but i failed to do so.

Do you know what could it be?

Thanks in advance :)